# Will giving Windmill a gun disqualify me for the Pacifist achievement?

Tags: achievements, deus-ex-human-revolution

[Reprogrammed turrets which kill people will disqualify you for the pacifist achievement](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29049/do-turrets-and-robots-killing-enemies-count-for-the-pacifist-achievement), so I'm forced to wonder if giving  Windmill  a gun will result in the same thing.

If I give Windmill a gun, will it disqualify me from the pacifist achievement?

Comment: I've never actually seen Windmill fight. All I saw him do was go and hide.

Comment: you scared the crap out of me with this question. i am on my second playthrough for pacifist and I just cleared the part where I gave him a gun.

Comment: The thing is he doesn't actually kill anyone that you encounter ingame with the gun, so I don't see how this can affect the achievement. The only part it affects in the game is you get 2000 credits from him while you are looking for the dragon queen in Tai Yong Medical, if you gave him a gun earlier.

Comment: Even the truly insane Don Quixote should think twice about going up against an armed windmill.

Comment: @Nickt Very true. Windmills are very bad ass after all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, you won't get disqualified from the pacifist achievement, because it's windmill doing the killing not you. With robots and turrets you indirectly told them to target enemies.

I gave Windmill a gun and I still got the pacifist achievement.

Answer (score -2):

Heh, I wasn't going to hand over my assault rifle or 10mm over to a turd like Windmill after I'd spent so much resources beefing them up (on my first playthrough and not going for the Pacifist achievement as yet).

But yeah I've seen this question asked before and Pacifist won't be affected.